# AngularJS - Window alert onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alert

I am just using the fantastic library that is angularJS. I am trying to get a simple window alert to come up on page load. This is the code I am using:

```
$scope.greet = function() {
    ($window.mockWindow || $window).alert('Hello World');
  }
}
```

I am new to javascript generally and it seems I have made a mistake with this because it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/AQ533/5/

Can anyone show me what it should be please? Thank you.

Comment: How do you call `greet`?

Comment: I guess I don't, it was left over from an example. I just want it to run on page load, so is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Just add ng-init="greet()" in your <body> tag,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to inject [`$window` service](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.%24window):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope , $window) {
  $scope.greet = function() {
    ($window.mockWindow || $window).alert('Hello');
  }
});
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/uO9l7n?p=preview

Comment: liked call from directive without pressing button +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure what you want to see with your example but this is working code:

```
<html ng-app>
 <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <span id="logo">Just a</span><span id="small" >PREVIEW</span>

   <button class="btn-large" ng-click="greet()">Press</button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $window) {
  $scope.greet = function() {
  ($window.mockWindow || $window).alert('Hello');
  }
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ533/6/)**</kbd>

Hope it will help you