# angularjs & ui-router - Why home's controller isn't working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

folks.

As the snippet shows, home's controller isn't working. I think it should work, but maybe I'm missing something.

I'm thinking that controller definition is in the wrong place, but that's the thing, I don't know where to place it.

Help is all I ask.

```js
angular
 .module("uiRouterSample",['ui.router'])
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
    url: '/',
          controller: ['$scope', '$state',
              function ($scope,   $state) {
                 alert("Hola")
              }]
   })
   .state('first', {
    url: '/first',
                views:{
                  "content":{
                    template:'<p>I\'m on the first page!</p>'
                  }
                }
   })
   .state('second', {
    url: '/second',
                views:{
                  "content":{
                    template:'<p>I\'m on the second page!</p>'
                  }
                }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="uiRouterSample">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <a ui-sref="first">Go to first</a> | 
  <a ui-sref="second">Go to second</a>
  <ui-view name="content"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a wrong place to define a controller. it should be in another file with a a unique name. and that name should be in your  `$stateProvider`. also i think you will need another  `ui-view` without "content" because home don't have a view name

Comment: Oh man, you're right, it's working for me. Now, would I be wrong if I wrap the whole app root in the empty `ui-view`???

Comment: yeah, if you don't have different's componets to load in one view e.g. custom navbar for sessions. you can wrap that in one view perfectly

Comment: Yes, I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, doesn't look like you're far off. Here's the Angular documentation for [setting up a controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) which might make things look cleaner.

Looks like the only bit not working is the alert. If you're looking to pop open an alert window, you should checkout the Angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window).

And [here's a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813141/angularjs-window-alert-onload) asking how to do this on page load instead of using a button like in the documentation.

Comment: if you're referring $window, don't worry, I'm aware of that. Thanks for the controller thing.

Comment: Ah, I see. Np. You can also just add reference to the app at the top of your html doc like so: ```<html ng-app="app">``` right below the doctype then you can just wrap things that need access to controllers in ```<div ng-controller="appController"></div>``` and do ng-includes for adding multiple page views: ```<div ng-include="'/path/to/page1.html'"></div>``` then you can have a separate views folder with all your pages in it. Which keeps things looking cleaner. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The home state that you have defined should be defined in this format

```
.state('home', {
          url: '/',
          views:{
              "content":{
                  controller: ['$scope','$state',function ($scope,$state) {
                      alert("Hola")
                  }]
              }
          }

      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering Paulo Galdo Sandoval's ideas, I reached the solution of this way.

```js
angular
 .module("uiRouterSample",['ui.router'])
    .run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
        //global handlers and properties
        $rootScope.origin = "I come from $rootScope!";
    }])
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
    url: '/',
          controller: ['$scope', '$state',
              function ($scope,   $state) {
                 alert("Hola")
              }]
   })
   .state('first', {
    url: '/first',
                views:{
                  "content":{
                    template:'<p>I\'m on the first page!<hr/>{{origin}}</p>'
                  }
                }
   })
   .state('second', {
    url: '/second',
                views:{
                  "content":{
                    template:'<p>I\'m on the second page!<hr/>{{origin}}</p>'
                  }
                }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="uiRouterSample">
  <ui-view>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <a ui-sref="first">Go to first</a> | 
    <a ui-sref="second">Go to second</a>
    <ui-view name="content"/>
  </ui-view>
</div>
```